# Understanding token pasting

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Please consider the following code snippet,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define AB "HELLO"
#define A "WORLD"
#define MAC1 A##B
void main(void)
{
    printf(MAC1"\n");
}
```

When compiled and executed prints HELLO.
Please help in understanding why `##` are ignored between `A` and `B`.

Also when the following code is compiled, gives following error,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define AB "HELLO"
#define A "WORLD"
#define MAC2 A#B
void main(void)
{
    printf(MAC2"\n");
}
```

> 21.c: In function âmainâ:
>   21.c:11:2: error: stray â#â in program
>   21.c:11:9: error: expected â)â before string constant

Why this behaviour?

Comment: ## is token/symbol concatenation, # takes its operand and turns it into a string (for example #define mac(x) #x , if I pass mac(myVar) I get "myVar" in it's place. For literal string concatenation, just place them next to eachother (like "Hello" "World", or in #define MAC1 AB A)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `##` preprocessing token is used for *token pasting*.

The effect of `A##B`, inside a macro definition, is to produce the token `AB`.  So `printf(MAC1"\n")` is the same as `printf(AB"\n")`.

The token is not "ignored", it's doing its job.

---

In your second example, `A#B` just means literally `A#B`. The `#` only has special meaning in a function-like macro. So your code expands to:

```
printf(A#B"\n");
```

which is an error because `#` is not part of C syntax, outside the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

The tokens # and ## are special in macro expansions.  '##' is the token pasting operator.  It takes 2 symbols in the macro and binds them into one symbol.  This is useful for creating specialized names.

```
#define LINE_COUNTER   static int line## __LINE__ =0; line ## __LINE__ ++;
```

This creates a variable which gets incrememented when the line gets executed.  It can be used multiple times in the same function, as it has a unique name based on the line number.  ( static int line_17 = 0;  line_17 ++; )

The '#' symbol is the stringizing operator.  It turns what follows it to a string.

```
#define assert( x )  if( ! x ) { fprintf( stderr, "Assertion failed %s\n", #x ); exit(  1 ) }
```

Comment: above answer is not clear enough, can you please give it in clear format?

Answer (score 0):

The ## concatenates symbols. In otherwords, A##B means AB which is nonexistent.
If you wanted to do something like make a variable name from 2 variable names, you could use that this way:

```
#define newVar(x,y) x##y

int main()
{
    int newVar(my,Var); // int myVar;
    newVar(f,printf)(stdout,"Hello World"); // fprintf(stdout,"Hello World");
}
```

# takes a name, and turns it into a string. for example

```
#define VARSTR(x) #x

int main()
{
    printf(VARSTR(myVar));
}
```

prints "myVar" to the string (even though myVar is not a variable of main, it is within the macro replacement)

```
 #define "HELLO" "WORLD"
```

To concatenate string literals they merely need to be placed next to each other with no other valid tokens between. So that results in "HELLOWORLD" Note that the white space between the literals is ignored, and unnecessary. I used that to clarify it.

This will replace AA and BB like this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define AA "HELLO"
#define BB "WORLD"
#define MAC1 AA BB
void main(void)
{
    printf(MAC1"\n"); // printf("HELLO" "WORLD""\n");
    // same as printf("HELLOWORLD\n");
}
```

Comment: This will result in a compiler error. `#define MAC1 A##B` will create the symbol `AB` wich is unknown to the compiler.

Comment: The "fixed" version is correct code but not what OP is asking about. He doesn't have a typo, he wants to understand what the behaviour is of his code.

Answer (score 0):

As other pointed out the `##` operator is used for creating new tokens. 
`#define MAC1 A##B` will create the macro `AB` wich was defined to contain the string `HELLO`. This is the reason `printf(MAC1"\n")` prints "HELLO". If you want to concat the strings represented by `AB` and `A` you can define `MAC1` as follows:

```
#define MAC1 AB A
```

Your preprocessor will then first replace `AB B` with `"HELLO""WORLD` so `MAC1` would look like that

```
#define MAC1 "HELLO""WORLD"
```

then it will replace `MAC1` everywhere it appears. So your printf statement would be

```
printf("HELLO""WORLD""\n"); // --> HELLOWORLD
```

Comment: actually, it would replace the AB A with "HELLO" "WORLD" in the macro first. Then MAC1 would be replaced with "HELLO" "WORLD" (not AB A first) Unless I'm mistaken, it reads from top to bottom of the file and replaces in that order, since AB and A are defined first, they are replaced into MAC1, Then the printf(MAC1...) gets its replacement later. Not that it matters, it all happens the same way in the end.